# matrix A=M-N and if $\lambda_{min}(M)> \rho(N)$, then $M$x$_{k+1}$=$N$x$_k+$b converges to x

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fixed-point-iteration

Consider the linear system $A$**x**=**b**, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Suppose that $M-N$ is a splitting of $A$, where $M$ is symmetric positive definite and $N$ is symmetric. Show that if $\lambda_{min}(M)> \rho(N)$, then the iterative scheme $M$**x**$_{k+1}$=$N$**x**$_k+$**b** converges to **x**for any initial guess **x**$_0$.

So I want to prove that if the minimum eigenvalue of $M$> maximum absolute eigenvalue of $N$, then $M$**x**$_{k+1}$=$N$**x**$_k+$**b** converges to **x** for all **x**$_0$.

I have no idea where to start. Some hints on where to start are appreciated. I prefer no full answers so I can try to finish the problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enough information to show
$$ \|M^{-1}\|_2 < \|N\|_2^{-1}$$
This will imply that
$$ \|M^{-1} N \|_2 < 1$$
which is enough to ensure convergence of the stationary iteration.

You will need to use the connection between eigenvalues and the 2-norm of symmetric matrices to derive the first inequality.